# How can I use cucumber to test a form that uses the nested_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, nested-forms

I'm using the rather lovely [nested form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) by Ryan Bates. It works fine when I use it live, but I haven't found a way of testing with Cucumber. I'm not trying to test the gem itself, but the behaviour of my website after I've completed the form.

The steps I'm using are exactly the same as the ones I'd use on the site.

```
Then I should see "Add a question"                       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105
When I follow "Add a question"                           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
  You might have expected an instance of Array.
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.[] (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: did you enable the javascript engine for cucumber at this point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the gem uses javascript to perform the browser magic, the scenario needs the @javascript tag.

Works fine now.